# Azure Webapps for Containers connection string in environment variables

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

My app running in a docker container on Azure Webapps for Containers tries to access a connection string through an environment variable. I've added it to the Application Settings in the Azure UI but I can't access it through my code, specifically my ASP.NET Core application is returning null.

I know that the logs won't show it being added as a `-e connstring=myconnstring` argument in the `docker run` command, but it should never the less be present in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, by using the Advanced Tools -> Environment Kudu service in Azure, the connection string environment variable names were being prefixed with `SQLAZURECONNSTR_`.

I know it is a convention to have these kind of prefixes on environment variables when reading them with the .NET Core environment variable configuration provider as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#prefixes), but quite why Azure adds these prefixes automatically, apparently without documenting this behaviour anywhere, is unclear to me.